# How do I add a property on a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am using normalizer on a redux state, and I have to add a loading object for the UI indicator,

So if we assume this is my normalized object:

```
const myState  = {
   obj1: {
    a:1,
    b:2
   },
   obj2: {
    a:2,
    b:3
   }
}
```

This is what I want to do, on properties obj1, and obj2: I want to dynamically add this object:

```
loading:{ update_a: false }
```

How do I do it? I don't what to manipulate the array on the [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) response; I'm doing it on the reducers.

Comment: Well, you're defining a constant but you wan't to change it? what do you mean dynamically?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myState).map(([k, v]) => [k, { ...v, loading: { update_a: false }}]));`

Comment: i never knew such thing about entries @JaredSmith, easier to maintain, would accept if u answered

Comment: @iamgpbaculio done and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll pull the existing state apart and build a new version with the added property we want:

```
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(myState)
    .map(([key, obj]) => [
      key, 
      { 
        ...obj, // copy properties from the existing obj
        loading: { // and add the loading property
          update_a: false 
        }
      }
    ])
);
```

Hopefully a little easier to read than my one-line version in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

We can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(myState).reduce((acc, key) => {acc[key] = {...myState[key],loading:{ update_a: false } }; return acc;},{})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that using `Object.entries` and `reduce`

```js
const myState = {
  obj1: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  obj2: {
    a: 2,
    b: 3
  }
}

const res = Object.entries(myState).reduce((all, [key, value]) => {
  all[key] = {
    ...value,
    loading: {
      updated_a: false
    }
  }
  return all;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```